# Get variable from Sencha Touch Ext.data.JSONP.request response

Tags: html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, jsonp, sencha-architect

I'm trying to get a boolean (success) and a HTML string (result) from the response to an `Ext.data.JsonP.request`, but I can't fgure out how. Here's the code I have so far:

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url: 'http://wereani.ml/shorten-app.php',
    callbackKey: 'callback',
    params: {
        data: Ext.encode(values)
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
        console.log('Link Shortened');
        if(response.responseText['success'] == true) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Link Shortened', response.responseText, Ext.emptyFn);
        } else {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', response.responseText, Ext.emptyFn);
        }
        form.reset();
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
        console.log('Error');
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Please try again.', Ext.emptyFn);
    }
});
```

Some sample JSON-P:

```
callback({"success":false,"result":"<div class=\"error\">Please enter a valid link to shorten!<\/div>"})
```

The error I'm currently getting is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined`.
Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT: It seems that while `response` is `Object {success: false, result: "<div class="error">Please enter a valid link to shorten!</div>"}`, `response.responseText` is `undefined`. Am I using the wrong variable? I couldn't find any documentation on `response`.

EDIT 2: It seems that the reason `Console.log(response.responseText)` was returning undefined is because it.... was. The JsonP-encoded variables (`success` and `result`) that I passed were parsed automatically into the object, and `response.responseText` was never created (though I think it was supposed to be). The solution was to just read `response.success` and `response.result` directly!

ANSWER: Here's the code that worked. Thanks to Viswa for the help!

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url: 'http://wereani.ml/shorten-app.php',
    callbackKey: 'callback',
    params: {
        data: Ext.encode(values)
    },
    success: function(response) {
        if(response.success === true) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Link Shortened', response.result, Ext.emptyFn);
        } else {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', response.result, Ext.emptyFn);
        }
        form.reset();
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        console.log('Error');
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', '<div class="error">Please try again.</div>', Ext.emptyFn);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url: 'http://example.com/script.php',
    callbackKey: 'callback',
    params: {
        data: Ext.encode(values)
    },
    success : function(response) {
      console.log("Spiffing, everything worked");
      // success property
      console.log(response.success);
      // result property
      console.log(response.result);
   },
   failure: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Please try again.', Ext.emptyFn);
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems that `response.responseText` has been returning `undefined`. I've edited the question to add more details. Am I using the wrong variable?

Comment: I figured it out! `response.responseText` doesn't exist, but my JsonP variables do. It seems that the extra `JSON.parse` is only necessary for other types or requests. Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad that you figured it out and  can you update my answer with what you figured.. so that it helps others or update your question with  answer

Comment: I'll edit the question, that way I can copy and paste my new code and the differences will be easier to see.

Comment: I can also update your answer, in case that helps someone else later.